# Where are the 'obstacle', 'volume initialization' and 'slip type' fluid options?

Tags: interface, physics, fluid-simulation

I downloaded Blender and I have been trying to do the fluid simulation. But I can’t find the, obstacle, volume initialization and slip type amongst other things in the Fluid panel.

[image]

Comment: Next time use screen capture software, if you could.

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with clearer pictures. And also, in future, please make the title of your question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic.

Comment: Thank you for the edit ... I hope I get an answer as soon as possible