# Fluid simulation - Where are the slip options for domain boundary and collision effectors in Blender 2.82 and above?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I'm sure I've seen these options before, but I really can't find the settings for the slip type in Blender's UI - at least not in 2.82. I found them in the documentation for 2.80:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/physics/fluid/types/obstacle.html
They have apparently vanished from the documentation for version 2.82. Is this feature gone?

I've set an object to be a collider in the fluid simulation, and it is working. But these are the only settings I can find...

[image: Settings I see in the fluid section of the physics properties for my effector/collider object]

I also couldn't find any images or video tutorials showing where the slip type options are located (not even for 2.80).

P. S.: The slip option question has actually been asked by someone on here, but people apparently refused to answer the question and instead focused on criticising the quality of the (in my opinion) reasonably clear photo that was attached there: [Where are the 'obstacle', 'volume initialization' and 'slip type' fluid options?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175908/where-are-the-obstacle-volume-initialization-and-slip-type-fluid-options)

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing - I've only been using blender for a couple of weeks and have found very quickly that they like changing the interface and features radically - even on minor releases. It's so infuriating that almost all the tutorials are for previous versions with very different interfaces. Aaaaaaaaaarghh!